# Initializer list not working in Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 CTP 4 (March)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, initializer-list

After installing Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 CTP 4 (March), this code doesn't compile:

```
vector<int> b = {1, 2, 3};
```

with the following error message:

```
'std::vector<_Ty>' : Types with a base are not aggregate
```

Earlier post about the same issue with previous CTP mentioned using initializer_list header, but CTP 4 didn't install it. Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: I don't see anything about the more recent CTPs adding more mature C++11 support. So there's no reason to expect the March CTP to be any different from the November CTP in this regard.

Comment: @Nicol: In addition to that, those 2 CTP's are *completely disjoined*. The November CTP was purely for MSVC, the Update 2 CTPs are, well, for Update 2.

Comment: @Nicol: Based on accepted answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559761/use-stdinitializer-list-in-visual-c-compiler-november-2012-ctp"), I thought that initializer_list header is available and fixes this problem.

Comment: @Xeo: Description of CTP 4 states: "Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 is a cumulative release", so I expected that all previous improvements will be there.

Comment: @Paul: As I said, "November CTP" vs "Update 2 CTP" are completely disjoined. One is an experimental update to a compiler, the other is for VS as a whole. And "Update 2" being a cumulative release most likely means that it contains Update 1.

Comment: @Xeo: OK, I get it now. It is a little bit confusing, since sequential, cumulative upgrades are an industry standard. OTOH, Visual Studio is a large collection of products.

Comment: @PaulJurczak: Yes, `initializer_list` is available. But that doesn't actually put the code in `std::vector` that *uses* `initializer_list`. That's what's missing from the November CTP.

Comment: `<initializer_list>` is available so you can write *your own* functions that take an `std::initializer_list` as a parameter, *but* the existing library hasn't been updated to include them in the existing classes.

Comment: @Xeo: So that means if I want the most recent C++11 features, even if I've already installed Update 2, I should still install November CTP?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler supports initializer lists, but the standard library (std::vector etc.) does not. You will have to wait before your line compiles.