# C++ Variadic Function Templates of Known Type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'm currently trying to get my head around some of the things I can do with variadic template support. Let's say I have a function like this -

```
template <typename ... Args>
void foo(Args ... a)
{
    int len = sizeof...(tail);
    int vals[] = {a...};
    /* Rest of function */
}

/* Elsewhere */
foo(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

This code works because I assume beforehand that the arguments will be integers, but obviously will fail if I provide something else. If I know that the parameter packs will contain a particular type in advance, is there some way that I can do without the templating and have something like -

```
void foo(int ... a)
```

I have tried doing this, but the compiler gave an error about foo being a void field. I know that I can also access the parameters in the pack through recursion, but I'm not sure this will fix the problem that I have - namely I want to be able to take a variable number of arguments of the same type.

Comment: You can use `enable_if` to make sure all types *are* ints.

Comment: The code works if you dive it a bunch of ints. It doesn't work if you give it something else. Looks like mission accomplished. Where is the problem?

Comment: I guess the issue is whether it's possible to ensure that they are ints at compile time.

Comment: A `static_assert` would also work here, instead of `enable_if`. Both use `is_same` from `<type_traits>`.

Comment: @znby If anything in the body of `foo` requires all the types to be `int`s or convertible to `int`s - e.g. `int vals[] = {a...};` - and
you code a call in which they aren't then you *will* know that
at compiletime.

Comment: If it does compile, they are `int`s, or at least something very close (`short`s should be equally good, while a `double` would break it). There's nothing to ensure any further.

Comment: @KerrekSB could you write an answer to demonstrate?

Comment: @M.M: For C++11, or for C++17? It'd be quite a bit easier for 17.

Comment: @KerrekSB It is tagged C++11 so I guess the former?

Answer (score 16):

This should work:

```
void foo(int);

template<typename ...Args>
void foo(int first, Args... more)
{
   foo(first);
   foo(more...);
}
```

Comment: This answer is more fitting for what the OP was asking for. The only downside of this solution is the recursion part. But right now I can see a better solution, not even by using C++17 and fold expressions.

Comment: @mic what is the better solution?  Drawback of this solution is that it can't take 0 parameters.

Comment: @candy-chiu There is  a typo in my last comment: "But right now I **can't** see ..." (just to clarify). Apart from this, you can easily add another overload: `foo()` to support 0 parameters.

Comment: `std::forward` is redundant unless `Args&&` was used instead of `Args`

Answer (score 10):

If you know the types before, you can use function overload with [`std:initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) :

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

void foo( std::initializer_list<int> l )
{
    for ( auto el : l )
        // do something
}

void foo( std::initializer_list<float> l )
{
}

void foo( std::initializer_list<std::string> l )
{
}

int main()
{
    foo( {1, 2, 3, 4 } );
    foo( {1.1f, 2.1f, 3.1f, 4.1f } );
    foo( { "foo", "bar", "foo", "foo" } );
    return 0;
}
```

If you use Visual Studio 2012, you might need the [**Visual C++ Compiler November 2012 CTP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238442/initializer-list-not-working-in-visual-studio-2012-update-2-ctp-4-march).

**EDIT :** If you still want to use variadic template, you can do :

```
template <int ... Args>
void foo( )
{
    int len = sizeof...(Args);
    int vals[] = {Args...};
    // ...
}

// And

foo<1, 2, 3, 4>();
```

But you have to remember that it is not working with `float` and `std::string` for example : you will end with `'float': illegal type for non-type template parameter`. `float` is not legal as a `non-type template parameter`, this is to do with precision, floating point numbers cannot be precisely represented, and the likelyhood of you referring to the same type can depend on how the number is represented.

Comment: If you need to know the number of arguments at compile-time this workaround is not sufficient though, because `initializer_list` does not provide a `constexpr size()` member. AFAIK, there is no way around variadic templates with `is_same<>/is_convertible<>` checks.

Comment: @user2523017 You are right, with this solution we can't have the number of arguments at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm currently trying to get my head around some of the things I can do with variadic template support.

Assuming that you want to experiment with variadic templates, not find **any** solution to your problem, then I suggest taking a look at the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int ...Values>
void foo2()
{
    int len = sizeof...(Values);
    int vals[] = {Values...};

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << vals[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo2<1, 2, 3, 4>();

    return 0;
}
```

The difference between `foo2` and your `foo` is that you pass the parameters to `foo` at runtime, and to `foo2` at compilation time, so for every parameter set you use, compiler will generate separate `foo2` function body.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of the top answer which will reject implicit conversion to `int` , if that is your preference:

```
#include <type_traits>

void foo(int);

template<typename Arg1, typename ...Args>
void foo(Arg1 first, Args... more)
{
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<Arg1, int>, "foo called with non-int argument");
   foo(first);
   foo(more...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, there's no point using variadic templates with parameters pack of the same types, but in a c++11-enabled compiler would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename ... Args>
void foo(Args ... args) {
    using type = typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
    const auto len = std::tuple_size<std::tuple<Args...>> {};
    type vals[] = {args...};

    for (size_t it = 0; it < len; ++it) {
        std::cout << vals[it] << std::endl;
    }
}

int32_t main(int argc, char** argv) {
    foo(1, 2);
    foo(1.1, 2.2);
    foo("1", "2");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```